# htaccess - rewriting this url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm struggling with my htaccess URL redirection. The URL is as follows..

> http://domain.com/comments/25/list/2

- comments/25 - 25 is the ID for the post
- list/2 - 2 is the page number I need to paginate from

I have the following for a previous page.

> RewriteRule ^channels/list/([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=channels&part=$1 [L]

So basically, need to re-write 2 variables and I'm struggling to do this. Sorry I cant explain it better :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> RewriteRule ^comments/([0-9]+)/list/([0-9]+)$
>   /index.php?comments=$1&list=$2 [L]